# How do I plot (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) and so on, on a Polar Plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I recently downloaded Mathematica and am extremely new to the software. To start off, I wanted to work with Polar Coordinates and Archimedean Spirals. I want to be able to graph a continuous spiral with the coordinates (r, theta)=(n, n) where n is a positive integer. Essentially I would be creating a spiral between the points (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) and it continues on. I would like to have a graph with just the points as well as one with a line connecting the points.

Also, is there a way to specify different ranges?

Similar to the question posed on this [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885879/meaning-of-rays-in-polar-plot-of-prime-numbers).

Comment: F1 takes you to the docs. Search 'Polar'.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is as follows.

```
a = ListPolarPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}},PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
f = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}];
b = PolarPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}];
Show[{a, b}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to add that `PolarPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]` works too.

Comment: `a = ListPolarPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 1.1}, {2.1, 2}, {3.3, 3}, {5, 5}, {8,       8.1}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]; f = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1.1}, {2.1, 2}, {3.3, 3}, {5, 5}, {8,       8.1}}]; b = PolarPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 13.5}]; Show[a, b, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: `a = ListPolarPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 1.1}, {2.1, 2}, {3.3, 3}, {5, 
    5}, {8,       8.1}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]; f = = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1.1}, {2.1, 2}, {3.3, 3}, {5, 
    5}, {8,       8.1}}]; b = PolarPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]; Show[a, b, 
 PlotRange -> All] ` works well. Everything has its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand , you want this and this or this

```
ListPolarPlot[Table[{j, j}, {j, 0, 10}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[.03]}]

ListPolarPlot[Table[{j, j}, {j, 0, 10}], Mesh -> {Range[0, 10]}, 
    MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[.03]}, Joined -> True]

PolarPlot[th, {th, 0, 10}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 10]}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[.03]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to Archimedean Spirals,so we can set the form `r == a*θ^(1/n)` and then solve the equations.

```
polarpts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
sol = Solve[
   r == a*θ^(1/n) /. Thread[{r, θ} -> #] & /@ polarpts, 
   Reals];
ArchimedeanSpirals = 
  PolarPlot[a*θ^(1/n) /. sol[[1]], {θ, 0, 20}, 
   MeshStyle -> Red];
Show[ArchimedeanSpirals, ListPolarPlot[polarpts, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

**Reply to comment**

Here we insist on using Archimedean Spirals.

```
polarpts = {{1, 1.1}, {2.1, 2}, {3.3, 3}, {5, 5}, {8, 8.1}};
f = NonlinearModelFit[Reverse /@ polarpts, 
   a*θ^(1/n), {a, n}, θ];
Show[PolarPlot[f[θ], {θ, 0, 20}], 
 ListPolarPlot[polarpts, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: The above does not work for `polarpts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1.1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};`, whereas `Interpolation` still does.

Comment: @user64494 But `Interpolation`  not always be Archimedean Spirals. The question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the function `FromPolarCoordinates`.

Unfortunately this function doesn't transform the Point `{0,0}`, That's why I used my own transformation:

```
r\[Theta] = Table[{i, i}, {i, 0, 10}]
xy = Map[#[[1]] {Cos[#[[2]]], Sin[#[[2]]]} &, r\[Theta]];
ListPlot[{xy, xy}, Joined -> {False, True}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: `f = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}];PolarPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}]` draws a spiral  along these points.